# How can I create a page based on image size in PDF::API2?

Tags: perl, image, pdf-generation

I am creating a pdf from a list of image files and I was wondering if it was possible to create each page of my pdf to be the size of whatever image I am currently adding - so they all fit and none of the larger ones get cropped or whatever.

Currently I'm creating pages like this: `my $page = $pdf->page();`

I have an object of the specific image as well. And if someone could tag this as PDF::API2 that'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to look at `$pdf->mediabox()`, `$pdf->cropbox()`, `$pdf->bleedbox()`, and `$pdf->trimbox()`.

You probably want to find the PDF spec to determine how these work, though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of this purely for on-screen viewing?  If print-size doesn't matter, you can do something like this:

```
use PDF::API2;
my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();

foreach my $filename (@list_of_jpeg_locations) {
    my $image = $pdf->image_jpeg($filename);

    my $width  = $image->width();
    my $height = $image->height();

    # Set the page size to equal the image size
    my $page = $pdf->page();
    $page->mediabox($width, $height);

    # Place the image in the bottom corner of the page
    my $gfx = $page->gfx();
    $gfx->image($image, 0, 0);
}

$pdf->saveas('/path/to/file.pdf');
```

You can tweak this code to scale the images to fit a particular printed page size, if need be.